# Sorting array in ascending and descending order with special characters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array that contains special characters(German language).This is sort function for a table so I have some columns that have true/false value. I have written a function for sorting and it works for ascending order, true/false order but not working for descending order.

```
return sortItems.sort((a, b) => {
    const firstItem = (typeof a[options.field] === 'string')
        ? a[options.field].toLowerCase()
        : a[options.field];

    const secondItem = (typeof b[options.field] === 'string')
        ? b[options.field].toLowerCase()
        : b[options.field];

    if (firstItem < secondItem) {
        if (typeof firstItem === 'string') {
            if (firstItem.localeCompare(secondItem) < secondItem.localeCompare(firstItem)) {
                return (options.asc) ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (firstItem.localeCompare(secondItem) > secondItem.localeCompare(firstItem)) {
                return (options.asc) ? 1 : 1;
            }
        } else {
            return (options.asc) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    } else if (firstItem > secondItem) {
        if (typeof firstItem === 'string') {
            if (firstItem.localeCompare(secondItem) < secondItem.localeCompare(firstItem)) {
                return (options.asc) ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (firstItem.localeCompare(secondItem) > secondItem.localeCompare(firstItem)) {
                return (options.asc) ? 1 : 1;
            }
        } else {
            return (options.asc) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As I can see you have this line `return (options.asc) ? 1 : 1;` twice. Don't you need to return a `\-1` on these 2 lines ? In the other conditions, you did it...

Comment: Even though it would be better to handle everything in a single function you could also simply reverse the given Array by using `sortItems.reverse()`.

Comment: On which lines? @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Else statements are for columns that are not strings

Comment: @lejhbah On the 2 `else if ` when `secondItem` is greater than `firstItem`.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Oh tnx, that fixed it, I didn't notice it